# Hashmap value getting overwritten

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hashmap

I'm having my `Hashmap` as such as a global variable within my class:

```
private Map<String, CodaReportDTO> dateAndDTO = new TreeMap<>(); //hashmap for date and the dto
```

So the value here is a `DTO` which has properties which I had to fill in an excel. I'm trying to fill up only one field (which is numOfTxn from the DTO) using the key (the date). So basically i'm trying to print out the values of the `DTO` per day.

This is my [DTO class](http://pastebin.com/m5PNzVfN).

I'm trying to add values here to the `hashmap` as such for the number of days in a month:

```
private JSONObject postDataToElasticSearchForSuccessCount(String url, String operatorID) throws IOException, JSONException, ParseException {

    /*JSONObject jsonObject = elasticSearchDataReceiver.getResults(url);

    //getting the number of hits
    JSONObject totalHits = jsonObject.getJSONObject("hits");
    Object hitsCountForSuccessCount = totalHits.get("total");
    String hitCountForSuccessCount = hitsCountForSuccessCount.toString();

    if (Integer.parseInt(hitCountForSuccessCount) > 0) {
        codaReportDTO.setNumOfTxn(Integer.parseInt(hitCountForSuccessCount));
    }
    return new JSONObject(jsonObject.toString());*/

    JSONObject updatedJsonObject = null;
    String jsonBody;
    String monthName = Month.of(Integer.parseInt(excelMonth)).name();
    int numberOfDaysInAMonth = Utilities.getNumberOfDaysForMonth(Integer.parseInt(excelYear), monthName);

    //iterate over the month
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfDaysInAMonth; i++) {


        String day = appendZeroToDay(i);
        excelDateMonth = day + "-" + excelMonth;
        Date excelMonthOriginal = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM").parse(excelDateMonth);
        String formattedDate = String.valueOf(excelMonthOriginal);
        String MonthOnly = formattedDate.substring(4, 7);
        String DateOnly = formattedDate.substring(8, 10);
        String dateAndMonthFinal = DateOnly + "-" + MonthOnly;
        excelDateMonth = dateAndMonthFinal;

        String input = "{  \n" +
                "   \"query\":{  \n" +
                "      \"query_string\":{  \n" +
                "         \"query\":\"api:\\\"smsmessaging\\\" AND operatorid:" + operatorID + " AND transactionOperationStatus:\\\"\\\" AND responsecode:(200 201) AND year:" + excelYear + " AND month:" + excelMonth + " AND day:" + day + "\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "   },\n" +
                "   \"aggs\":{  \n" +
                "      \"total\":{  \n" +
                "         \"terms\":{  \n" +
                "            \"field\":\"userid\"\n" +
                "         },\n" +
                "         \"aggs\":{  \n" +
                "            \"grades_count\":{  \n" +
                "               \"value_count\":{  \n" +
                "                  \"script\":\"doc['userid'].value\"\n" +
                "               }\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "         }\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "   }\n" +
                "}\n";

        jsonBody = input;
        JSONObject jsonObject = elasticSearchDataReceiver.getResult(url, jsonBody);

        JSONObject totalHits = jsonObject.getJSONObject("hits");
        Object hitsCountForSuccessCount = totalHits.get("total");
        String hitCountForSuccessCount = hitsCountForSuccessCount.toString();
        int hitCount = Integer.parseInt(hitCountForSuccessCount);

        if (hitCount > 0) {
            updatedJsonObject = jsonObject;
            codaReportDTO.setNumOfTxn(hitCount);
            dateAndDTO.put(dateAndMonthFinal, codaReportDTO);
        }
    }
    return updatedJsonObject;
}
```

The hashmap adding part is at the bottom of the above snippet:

> dateAndDTO.put(dateAndMonthFinal, codaReportDTO);

The key and the value is coming correctly in the above line. But when it tries to update the value for the new key, it replaces the other values of keys  which have values with the new value. Where am I going wrong?

I've been trying this for the whole day after looking into other question here in the SO, but still couldn't get through. Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: `it replaces the other values of the others keys which have values to the new value` I'm not sure I understand that part. May you explain in more details what exactly is happening ?

Comment: Where is the instantiation of codaReportDTO? Could it be that you are using one instance for all values? This will explain the symptoms

Comment: @aviad i've made the instantiation globally within this class itself: `private CodaReportDTO codaReportDTO = new CodaReportDTO();`

Comment: Ok so you are using one DTO instance and all values are pointing to it. Every time you change it, obviously changes would reflect on other entries

Comment: @SvetlinZarev what i meant was, even though the key and the value is correct, when i'm trying to apply the put it resets all the other key values which have values already with the new value. Did I answer your question ?

Comment: If you dont want changes to be overriden, you need to create a new instance of the DTO for each new key

Comment: @aviad so I should be creating new DTO instances every time I add values to the key ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125801/discussion-between-kulasangar-and-aviad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same instance of your DTO for all the map's entries. This is why, each change is reflected on all values. If you dont want changes to be overriden, you need to create a new instance for each of the map's keys.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the way maps are used. If you want to use multiple values for the same key then you should use List<> as a second parameter for `Map<String, List<CodaReportDTO>>`